# How do I allow images in the HTMLPurifier?

Tags: php, html, frameworks, xss, htmlpurifier

I want to allow images within my HTML Purifier filter. Unfortunately they are still being filtered. WHat is wrong with this code?

```
$config->set('HTML.Doctype', 'XHTML 1.0 Transitional');
$config->set('URI.DisableExternalResources', false);
$config->set('URI.DisableResources', false);
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'u,p,b,i,span[style],p,strong,em,li,ul,ol,div[align],br,img');
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can we see some sample HTML you are trying to use? Are you trying to pull the image from an external site? More information please.

Answer (score 2):

You need to allow the src and alt attributes. HTML Purifier should probably warn you if you fail to allow a required attribute for an element/

Answer (score 2):

adding this line of code to yours should fix the problem:

```
$config->set('HTML.AllowedAttributes', 'src, height, width, alt');
```

Answer (score 1):

To accept b64 images you must add a new URIScheme:

```
 if(!class_exists("HTMLPurifier_URIScheme_data")){
        class HTMLPurifier_URIScheme_data extends HTMLPurifier_URIScheme {

            public $default_port = null;
            public $browsable = false;
            public $hierarchical = true;

            public function validate(&$uri, $config, $context) {
                return true;
            }

        }
    }

HTMLPurifier_URISchemeRegistry::instance()->register("data", new HTMLPurifier_URIScheme_data());
```

Source: http://htmlpurifier.org/phorum/read.php?3,4316,4318,quote=1

"Nick", the guy who made this code, said that had to set:

```
$browsable = true;
$hierarchical = false;
```

But in my case i didn't.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Purifier seek `http://` or `https://` after `src="` which may be missing while posting data (inline src="data:image/png;base64,.... ) or your link. Hope this will work for you too as it worked for me.